# segment Controller selector error?

Tags: objective-c

I have some problem with segment Controller on iphone when I want to change the shape or color it throw errors

```
  #import "BIDViewController.h"
#import "BIDQuartzFunView.h"
#import "BIDConstants.h"


@interface BIDViewController ()

@end

@implementation BIDViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender {
    UISegmentedControl *control = sender;
    NSInteger index = [control selectedSegmentIndex];

    BIDQuartzFunView *funView = (BIDQuartzFunView *)self.view;

    switch (index) {
        case kRedColorTab:
            funView.currentColor = [UIColor redColor];
            funView.useRandomColor = NO;
            break;
        case kBlueColorTab:
            funView.currentColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            funView.useRandomColor = NO;
            break;
        case kYellowColorTab:
            funView.currentColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            funView.useRandomColor = NO;
            break;
        case kGreenColorTab:
            funView.currentColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            funView.useRandomColor = NO;
            break;
        case kRandomColorTab:
            funView.useRandomColor = YES;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)changeShape:(id)sender {
    UISegmentedControl *control = sender;
    [(BIDQuartzFunView *)self.view setShapeType:[control selectedSegmentIndex]];
    if ([control selectedSegmentIndex] == kImageShape)
        _colorControl.hidden = YES;
    else
        _colorControl.hidden = NO;
}

@end
```

error:

> -[UIView setShapeType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x767a0a0
>   2013-05-14 22:42:15.836 QuartzFun[1014:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setShapeType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x767a0a0'

Comment: This means that `self.view` is a `UIView`, not whatever class has the `setShapeType:` method. Perhaps you added a `BIAQuartzFunView` as a subview of `self.view`.

Comment: can you explane how to fix it ?

Comment: Not with what little info you have provided. I assume `self` is a view controller. Did you add a `BIQDQuartzFunView` to the view hierarchy? You need to get a reference to that view. Then you can call your `setShapeType:` method.

Comment: I update my Code is what I do right ?

Comment: Assuming your `changeColor` method works, then change your `changeShape` method so you create the `funView` variable. Then call `setShapeType` on the variable.

Comment: even the changeColor is not working ??

Comment: Then that goes back to my very first comment. You have not yet answered my questions. Where do you create and add the `BIDQuartzFunView` view? Show that code.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are not initialized the BIDQuartzFunView properly, instead of this:

```
(BIDQuartzFunView *)self.view
```

Try this:

```
BIDQuartzFunView *funView = [[BIDQuartzFunView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]];
```

Then it should respond to setShapeView:

```
[funview setShapeView:[control selectedSegmentIndex];
```

Also don't forget to add the BIDQuartzFunView to the view:

```
[self.view addSubview:funView];
```

Comment: Shucks... are you getting the same error? The code you have above does not look right to me. But I could be wrong. I looks like you are not alloc'ing and init'ing the view properly. Also I do not see where you are adding the BIDQuartzFunView to the view.